# Typescript filter object by value of argument

Tags: typescript

I have a function inspired by Prisma which generates an SQL query string from an object, and then makes the SQL query request and returns the object retrieved.

Here's a [typescript playground (original code, see new below)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=54&ssc=42&pln=54&pc=19#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-XIi34l3+-XUCUx9WMzPGtvbNyHKgAHI7Y+IMEKEJ6BBn-vE4IKYAFRroWs4lp4Tz4IQk4ImgM7FmUQh4AAklAfyFowUABn0XQQbkUCyAeC7rpuYicqYt6Lke5GxrYVEXo4JilAebhASmJAdl2YHFgATAk-aDiWFxXBWpzAiRcI-iuybnmR26nge1FWIp56XrRql3geD5Pq+76ft+v7-gmgEgd24H8ZBBDQdkeQFEUzGfFA3y-ACsRIah6GYfmOHQEOwAEURi4kRuVguf83AMTR27hQCDHqTF3A-BFt5sRxXEljx2AAMwCQOQ4iaOtwTggcEYD2wDztp7IsHpUgfl+P5-iQAEkMBoEVblVnQTBpXIPBFXobyNCILyXSZHyuZ4WwvLeYREAAHQkOx7hplAACqcL5gF5wULh5g0D+5TnLkqDZotJApGA+Qlo2QA) of the code in a minimal reproduction.

I am currently using a type generic to set the expected output, but it always returns the full object, even if select is applied.

Is there a way to return the output type filtered as per the supplied select object if there is one? I've tried using keyof `(typeof query)["select"]` but this gets the key of the select type, not the supplied value at runtime.

Update: I've made some progress on this, I was able to get output2 and output3 to output the correct type, but still not output1.
Here's a new [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHpAxsCATA8gV2GbUC8UA3gFACQAhgGICWEANqgFxQDOwATjQHYDmA3OQBGtBsyjdMAWyEQOgsolGMW7LnwWpl4yTLkKI21Zx4DyAMyMTps+eV5W1pwQF8SJUJCjohAKwjI6BwAKhyYEAA8weAQAHwEUNFeEHAo3KisUABKAQD2HKgRTnwANFAU3CCx5AD8xFAA2gAKHLmQHKBQPFAA1hAgueaJMQC6LD7+gSFhkS1tcqDxbmQsnOGCJBSsINyIUOaYu8A0udxQUiBUh8gn3BHkSdApaRnZeQVFJqXllfGEOYh8oVirwyocetxcgB3bjVWIACgAjuEOCAWKQyKwGAFgDUWE0KB0aBR6BEiI05u1Ot0+gMho8xt4-DigqFwlEYs1WlSQCMlrEFOZWlJjOozGQoQALOQQPFQAlEklkinchYgLpnWmDYaQRmPLnzDq8qAuAXkIFyOUK45K8kGnka3r9bUMlgAIgAggBlADCbqgAB8oG6ACIwX3+00Keg0KQ0XEsXS2BSDcxYhPWPR2FwASmIJCgUEB3HYxCx9BxLgSyLkIA2ZAA9A2oF7Y5h6BQUKgoLlsLhgD2hgcjrcC11zPDyziCPhCIdUBBzDw0HnSIXC8XWLkKwA6ei5XjwgDkU+QXUy88Xy9QR5zgnXRdOW93+8PRBrqNz9-XHAgwEwHBnEQVZbDqEDfssv7-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-9gM0JkUqg4JrAQ+2UMQDDhaNSQbhUTRdEMcATFU0AA) link with the updated code, and I have updated the code in the post.

Playground Code:

```
type ExpectedOutput = {
    aField: string;
    bField: number;
    cField: string;
    dField: number;
    eField: string;
    fField: number;
    gField: string;
}

type ObjectOrTrue<Type> = Type extends Record<string, any>
    ? { [Property in keyof Type]: ObjectOrTrue<Property> }
    : true;

async function myFunction<
    Type extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, unknown>
>(query: {
    select?: Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: ObjectOrTrue<Type[Property]> }>;
    from: string;
    where?: Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property] }>;
    order?: Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: "ASC" | "DESC" }>;
    limit?: number;
    offset?: number;
}) {
  const {select} = query;

  // Simulated output of function
  if(select === undefined) {
    console.log('select is undefined');
    console.log({query});
    return {} as Type;
  }
  return {} as {[Property in keyof typeof select]: Type[Property]};
}
async function runAllTests() {
  const output1 = await myFunction<ExpectedOutput>({
    select: {
      aField: true,
      bField: true,
      cField: true,
    },
    from: 'SomeTable',
  });
  /*
  output1 type === ExpectedOutput, but I would like it to be
    {
      aField: string,
      bField: number,
      cField: string,
    }
  */
  const output2 = await myFunction({
    select: {
      aField: true,
      bField: true,
      cField: true,
    },
    from: 'SomeTable',
  });
  /*
  output2 type === {
      aField: unknown,
      bField: unknown,
      cField: unknown,
    } 
    which is what it should be.
  */
  const output3 = await myFunction<ExpectedOutput>({
    from: 'SomeTable',
  });
  /*
  output3 type === ExpectedOutput which is what it should be.
  */
}
runAllTests();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the return type depends on an argument type I usually resort to an extra generic. However, there's no way to pass one generic and infer the others so I decided to make `myFunction` a factory as sort of a hack.

If [this proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) passes we would be able to revert the factory.

```js
type ObjectOrTrue<Type> = Type extends Record<string, any>
  ? { [Property in keyof Type]: ObjectOrTrue<Property> }
  : true;

function myFunction<
  Type extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, unknown>
>() {
  return async <
    Select extends Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: ObjectOrTrue<Type[Property]> }> | undefined = undefined,
    MyReturnType = Select extends undefined
      ? Type
      : string extends keyof Type
      ? { [Property in keyof Select]: unknown }
      : { [Property in Extract<keyof Type, keyof Select>]: Type[Property] }
  >(query: {
    select?: Select;
    from: string;
    where?: Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property] }>;
    order?: Partial<{ [Property in keyof Type]: "ASC" | "DESC" }>;
    limit?: number;
    offset?: number;
  }): Promise<MyReturnType> => {
    const { select } = query;

    // Simulated output of function
    if (select === undefined) {
      console.log('select is undefined');
      console.log({ query });
      return {} as never;
    }

    return {} as never;
  }
}
```

Had to modify `runAllTests`, all I did was add `()` to every call:

```js
const output1 = await myFunction<ExpectedOutput>()({
  select: {
    aField: true,
    bField: true,
    cField: true,
  },
  from: 'SomeTable',
});
const output2 = await myFunction()({
  select: {
    aField: true,
    bField: true,
    cField: true,
  },
  from: 'SomeTable',
});
const output3 = await myFunction<ExpectedOutput>()({
  from: 'SomeTable',
});
```